# Unable to display images in my web page (Laravel built)

Tags: laravel

I have a form to display politician names and respective images in a `@foreach ($politicians as $politician)`. Db table has all the needed information about the name & image path where actual image is located in `public/storage/images/poltician_images`. Have the correct permission to access images: `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 173137 Mar  6 00:31 1709685078.PNG`

I have the correct `<image>` tag:

```
<img src="{{ asset($politician->image) }}" alt="{{ $politician->name }}" class="politician-img">
```

.env has `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public`

How ever when my index.blade.php page is loaded only the names are there no images displayed.

I tried with direct link to an image in the same directory and it works but if I use $solutions->image tag

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you've generated the storage:link then in the blade display tag you can adjust the img src and concatenate with the image path, or name you stored them in the public/storage/images/poltician_images folder

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/politician_images/' . $politician->image) }}" alt="{{ $politician->name }} Image">
```

Make sure to replace the image with the image path stored in the database

Comment: storage/images/politician_images are in publicly assessable off public director with the full path public/storage/images/politician_images. Do I still need to create a sym link

Comment: Yeah,You still need the sym link